# How do i turn all # tags into a hyperlink?

Tags: php

If this script detects then displays all # tags, how do i change it so it makes them all a hyper link? Basically putting an `<a href="#">`infront of it and a `</a>` behind

```
$str = <<<STR
this is a string
with a #tag and
another #hello one
STR;

$matches = array();
if (preg_match_all('/#([^\s]+)/', $str, $matches)) {
  var_dump($matches[1]);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Could you give an example?

Comment: He wants `#tag` to become `<a href="#">#tag</a>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use back-references, and [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace) to do this.

```
echo preg_replace('/#([^\s]+)/', '<a href="#">$1</a>', $str);
```

Output:

```
this is a string
with a <a href="#">tag</a> and
another <a href="#">hello</a> one
```

If you want the `#` to be part of the link, simply change the regex to `/(#[^\s]+)/`.

Demo: http://ideone.com/T06HQ

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to do this:

```
$str = <<<STR
this is a string
with a #tag and
another #hello one
STR;

$matches = array();
if (preg_match_all('/#([^\s]+)/', $str, $matches)) {
  // Get rid of the full matches
  array_shift($matches);
  // Now get the first array element which are the actual captured matches
  list($matches) = $matches;

  foreach($matches as $match) {
    echo "<a href='#'>{$match}</a>\n";
  }
}
```

Output:

```
$ php test.php 
<a href='#'>tag</a>
<a href='#'>hello</a>
```

Answer (score -3):

```
sed 's/#/URL/' myhtmlfile.html
```

Where URL is the url you want to replace the # with.

Comment: He wants to replace `#tag` with `<a href="#">#tag</a>`, and he also wants to do it inside his PHP script.